# how to configure LAN for my project

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have written programs for client-server architecture. How to configure these programs on LAN for Ubuntu so that a PC is running only client can access the server on another PC .

Comment: What do you mean by "client-server architecture"? Are your programs at application layer or is it using raw sockets? Are your programs running over TCP? UDP? What is the topology of your LAN? Do you have a firewall? This is vague, please add information.

Comment: it will run on application layer.

Comment: My programe is just multithreaded . i want to run different thread of client on different machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of IPTABLES to restrict the access to the server. In your case, you can add an IPTABLE rule on the server to accept connections only from the client.